# Firebase array of references

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

When trying to deal with an array of references I get the error "FirebaseError: Function Firestore.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: a custom t object"
My user doc has an array of references called reviews and I am trying to get the data of each of the references.

```js
const handleFetch = async () => {
    let db = firebase.firestore();
    let userRef = await db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(props.user.id.uid) //<- doc works and returns correctly
        .get();
    userRef.data().reviews.forEach((ref, indx) => {
        let hold = db.doc(ref).get(); //<- error occurs here

    });

}
```

Comment: Do a condition check on `props.user.id.uid` before u call firebase. console.log to see if it's a string or object.

Comment: That portion works, regardless I tried typeof and it printed a string.

Comment: well the error did pointed it out that it was an object. Can you add a condition check?

Comment: The object that errors out is in the ref objects that I get from the array. I am not sure how to access the reference "objects"

Comment: Oh my mistake. I don't know where you get your codes from, but instead of `ref` you should probably use `ref.data()` https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In firestore, a Reference object is constructed into a document or collection reference and you can invoke any of the document methods on it as needed.

```
const ref = snapshot.data().reviews[0];
ref.get();
ref.remove();
```

The error in particular is saying that the item is not a string, which if it is a firestore reference, is an object and thus, not compatible.

A great video to watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Elg2zDVIcLo&t=276s